# How to instantiate a new GameObject in another Transform with a random position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tunnel which I want to add some other game objects (like some boxes) inside it in a random position. The tunnel is not stright.

Until now I put some empty game objects in tunnel perfab at design time and then at runtime choose one of them in a random manner and then use its position for instantiating.

Is there any way to do this with code without headache of creating new prefabs?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (maybe not the most performant) would be to randomly generate vectors inside the boundingbox of your "tunnel"-Mesh and then  [check if the Vector is inside the tunnel.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/611947/am-i-inside-a-volume-without-colliders.html)